# Customize invitation email in Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I want to custom the invitation email when I share a google form. I have looking up in Google Script documentation and I haven't found some method or class useful. How can I customize this invitation email?.

Normally this email looks like:
[image]

I want to add a corporative image in the footer and maybe some text.

Comment: You can include a personal message, but you can not add an image or a footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a method to create your own customized message. Below I am going to propose an alternate solution.

You can create a function that sends a customized mail. Just create an HTML file with your customized HTML content.

```
// i called this share.html in the apps script project
<h1>This is a header 1</h1>

<p>This is a paragraph</p>

<img src="<<SOME IMAGE SRC HERE>>" />
```

Then back in your code.gs file create a function like below:

```
function shareForm() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('share').getContent();

  var recipient = '<<EMAIL ADDRESS>>';

  var subject = 'this is the subject';

  var body = 'this will get overridden by the HTML service';

  var options = {
    htmlBody: html
  };

  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)
}
```

You can run this function from the script editor, or you can build a button to add into the add-ons drop down options.

Comment: This definitely does not answer the question : "...when I share a google form"

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. There isn't a specific method available that allows you to customize the message that sends when you share a form. (At least I am not familiar with such a method). However, the function that I wrote is a way to create your own share function that sends an HTML formatted email.

Comment: I am going to use this option... for now. Thanks  @Jordan